# Trying to get music out from my iPod first generation, IOS level 1.1.5 (4B1), model MB376LL

Tags: ios, ipod-touch

I have som music on my [iPod touch, first generation](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/ipod/specs/ipod-touch-specs.html) which I want transferred to my current iTunes/iPhone (latest version). I am running windows 10 (64 bit).

My problem is that the old version of my iPod touch (IOS 1.1.5 (4B1), model MB376LL), iTunes will not accept it due to the very old version and cannot upgrade from iTunes.

If have tried to upgrade IOS version on iPod touch 1 generation by means of 'Whited00r' and Redsn0w, without success.

So hoe can I access the music stored on that iPod?

Comment: I wonder if something like iMazing or iExplorer would allow you to get your music off your iPod? I would check with their support folks and see what they say.

Comment: There also was a tool called senuTi once which allowed to transfer music from iPods to a computer. Not sure it is still around or still works with modern version of Windows/macOS.

Answer (score 2):

There is no official way to extract the tracks from an iDevice to a computer.
iTunes was always designed to be the master, any iDevice as merely a slave to that.

On Windows, however, it's much simpler than on Mac, because the device can be mounted to the computer like an external drive.
From [Wondershare - Top Ways to Extract Music from an iPod touch](https://drfone.wondershare.com/music-transfer/extract-music-from-ipod.html)
Note: they'd rather you bought their software to do this, but they include a manual method at the end.

> Extract Music from the iPod on PC
>
> Open "Computer" and you can see your iPod is displayed as a removable
> disk. Click Tools > Folder option > Show hidden files and folders on
> the ribbon and click "OK". Open "iPod-Control" folder in the removable
> disk and find the music folder. Add the folder to your iTunes Library.